# How to change the Android navigation bar color in a PWA?

Tags: html, google-chrome, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I would like to change the color of the Android navigation bar on the web when I add the page on the Android home screen (Progessive Web App) but when I open the PWA, the color of the Android navigation bar is black and I want Change the color to white. In the manifest, you can change the color of the theme and I do, but still follow the color black.

Is it possible to do that?

I mean the Android navigation bar, not the notification bar.

[image: Android navigation bar]

Comment: You want to change the color of the system buttons? I don't think this is possible, at least I havent seen any examples of it yet.

Comment: Yes, I want to change the color of the system buttons. Thanks for your answer I hope that in the future google add this. Then I finish this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know it is currently not a PWA supported feature.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a meta tag to your HTML page.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#225577"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean the android navigation bar. Not the notifications bar.

Comment: In PWA I think they are the same. Could you maybe edit the question with a screenshot showing your problem?

Comment: Ok, i uploaded the image.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is still no workaround for this in 2023.

The Android navigation bar's background color in PWAs depends on the theme setted in your phone settings. If your phone is set as dark mode, it will appear dark. Otherwise, it will appear as white in PWAs.

That's why it is probably a good idea to add toggle theme functionality in your PWA.

Comment: How does one toggle theme in PWA?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change navigation them color when you transfer your **'pwa'** into a **'twa'** android app using **bubblewrap**.

After initializing your project using bubblewrap you get the file **"twa-maifest.json"**

In this file you get json-code something like below

```
"navigationColor": "#000000",
"navigationColorDark": "#000000",
"navigationDividerColor": "#000000",
"navigationDividerColorDark": "#000000",
```

change those color-code according to your requirement then build your app.

I tried this and got result.

I hope you also get result as you want.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/codelabs/pwa-in-play#0

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `manifest.json` and set `"theme_color":"#000000"`, `"background_color": "#000000"` - your browser might pick those colors and apply them to the nav bar (or might not, Samsung's standard browser used to ignore this setting and never changed nav bar color). It seems there's still no such feature in PWA (which existis in Android native apps) that allows specifing navbar color alone.

Comment: This does not seem to work, at least for Vue2, unfortunately. Neither setting this (nor backgroundColor) in vue.config.js (pwa object).

Comment: Just an FYI, Vue has nothing to do with anything in your manifest file. Separation of concerns here. So this is not a Vue related question :)

Comment: I had my manifest set up already, but it turns out you have to turn off Dark Theme on the system for those to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

The color  of the navigation bar doesn't work with dark theme. Change to light theme and it will work.

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted your answer. This is the correct case. I spent several minutes not getting any changes to the notification bar, and suddenly everything looks fine with dark theme turned off. So is it impossible to do this with darktheme on?